# I tried installing crazyflie client in my macos. I am having the following error if I run cfclient

Tags: runtime-error, quartz.net, oserror, cfclient, crazyflie

(base) gdas@L-MAC-N02777 ~ % cfclient
UserWarning: Using SDL2 binaries from pysdl2-dll 2.24.0
INFO:cfclient.gui:Disabling STL printouts
INFO:cfclient.gui:Foundation not found. Menu will show python as application name
INFO:cfclient.utils.input.inputreaders:Input readers: ['linuxjsdev', 'pysdl2']
INFO:cfclient.utils.input.inputreaders:Could not initialize [linuxjsdev]: Only supported on Linux
INFO:cfclient.utils.input.inputreaders:Successfully initialized [pysdl2]
INFO:cfclient.utils.input.inputinterfaces:Found interfaces: ['leapmotion', 'wiimote', 'zmqpull']
INFO:cfclient.utils.input.inputinterfaces:Could not initialize [leapmotion]: Leap Motion library probably not installed (No module named 'leapsdk')
INFO:cfclient.utils.input.inputinterfaces:Could not initialize [wiimote]: Missing cwiid (wiimote) driver No module named 'cwiid'
INFO:cfclient.utils.config:Dist config read from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cfclient/configs/config.json
INFO:cfclient.utils.config:Config file read from [/Users/gdas/Library/Application Support/cfclient/config.json]
INFO:cfclient.utils.input.inputinterfaces:Could not initialize [zmqpull]: ZMQ input disabled in config file
===== 2024.01.17 12:01:37 =====
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/homebrew/bin/cfclient", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cfclient/gui.py", line 162, in main
from .ui.main import MainUI
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cfclient/ui/main.py", line 36, in 
import cfclient.ui.tabs
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cfclient/ui/tabs/**init**.py", line 42, in 
from .locopositioning_tab import LocoPositioningTab
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cfclient/ui/tabs/locopositioning_tab.py", line 52, in 
from vispy import scene
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vispy/**init**.py", line 27, in 
from .util import config, set_log_level, keys, sys_info  # noqa
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vispy/util/**init**.py", line 14, in 
from . import fonts       # noqa
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vispy/util/fonts/**init**.py", line 13, in 
from ._triage import _load_glyph, list_fonts  # noqa, analysis:ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vispy/util/fonts/_triage.py", line 14, in 
from ._quartz import _load_glyph, _list_fonts
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vispy/util/fonts/_quartz.py", line 12, in 
from ...ext.cocoapy import cf, ct, quartz, CFRange, CFSTR, CGGlyph, UniChar, 
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vispy/ext/cocoapy.py", line 1288, in 
quartz = cdll.LoadLibrary(util.find_library('quartz'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ctypes/**init**.py", line 454, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ctypes/**init**.py", line 376, in **init**
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: dlopen(Quartz.framework/Quartz, 0x0006): tried: 'Quartz.framework/Quartz' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSQuartz.framework/Quartz' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/lib/Quartz.framework/Quartz' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/lib/Quartz.framework/Quartz' (no such file), '/usr/lib/Quartz.framework/Quartz' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'Quartz.framework/Quartz' (no such file)

I reinstalled xcode and quartz but it didn't resolve the issue. The error persists if I run cfclient.

Comment: No, I switched to ubuntu to use it.